# how to check if bootstrap-4 modal already open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I want to check if a certain modal is already open , I have tried this methods (bootstrap-4) but didn't work for me (always give 'false' even if the dialog is open)

```
 $('#myModal').is(':visible');   
 $('#myModal').data('bs.modal').isShown ;        
 $('#myModal').hasClass('in');
```

I checked modal classList , no any new class added to my modal after it became visible to the screen

I don't want event handlers as I don't want to track the status , I just want to check if the dialog was previously open via some other function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when a bootstrap modal ([v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)) is **shown**, as far as i can notice, three things happens in the DOM, the modal gets a two classes named **fade** and **show** respectively, and a style property with *display* to *block* (and mybe others like *padding*...) and the *body* tag gets a class named **modal-open**. So realy all you have to do is to check for one of those things, i recommend to check the existing of the **show** class.

```
$('#exampleModal').hasClass('show'); // return true if the modal is open
```

or

```
$('body').hasClass('modal-open');
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Bootstrap modal</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
      
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
           
           setTimeout(function() {
              
              var isShown = $('#myModal').hasClass('show');
              console.log(isShown);
              
           }, 1000);
      
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when the dialog launched at the first time there is no any additional classes added

Comment: setTimeout worked (Y) , but is there another solution without depending on this value of timeout (i.e: 1000ms)

Comment: @Sara i think this may depend on how/when your script is executed.

Comment: more details please

Comment: it is the standard modal code from bootstrap examples without any change @chebaby

Comment: @Sara i'm little bit lost here... bootstrap examples works just fine!! i think what you may be asking for are modal events!! https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events

Answer (score 6):

Your modal will have the class `.show` if the modal has been shown via Bootstrap JS and so if you would like to see if the modal is currently open, you can check `$('#myModal').hasClass('show')`.

Comment: also returned false when the dialog open

Comment: What do you get when inspecting `$('#myModal')`? Please show us the result

Comment: i checked modal classList , no any new class added to my modal after it became visible to the screen

Comment: it returns only a plain text

Comment: What is this plain text? Are you entering just `$('#myModal')` on its own?

Comment: $('#myModal').modal();
  $('#myModal .modal-body').html('test');